# What is the most elegant way to find the sum of all numbers in a string in TCL?

Tags: tcl

What is the most elegant way to find the sum of all numbers in a TCL string of the following format ?
For eg.

```
set s1 "{A 30.8950} {B 29.5680} {C 20.5160}"
```

How to find the sum, 30.8950 + 29.5680 + 20.5160 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is *really* just floats in a string, you use something like:

```
set sum [tcl::mathop::+ {*}[regexp -all -inline {-?\d+(?:\.\d+)(?:e[-+]?\d+)} $theString]]
```

If it is more structured than that, such as a Tcl list of tuples where the second item of each tuple is the value to add, you might use:

```
set sum [tcl::mathop::+ {*}[lmap tuple $theList {lindex $tuple 1}]]
# Requires Tcl 8.6
```

Answer (score 2):

The 'elegant' approach resides on how you are extracting the required input.

The following one simply loops through the list and extracting the numerical values.

```
set s1 "{A 30.8950} {B 29.5680} {C 20.5160}"
set sum 0
foreach elem $s1 {
    # Extracting 2nd element to get the numerical value
    set num [lindex $elem 1]
    set sum [expr {$sum+$num}]
}

puts $sum
```

**Output :**

```
80.979
```